# apache2 virtual host proxy subdomain to another port on the same machine

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have php service running on mydomain.com, and I have node application running on mydomain.com:8000, now I try to map sub.mydomain.com to mydomain.com:8000 using apache's virtual host.

I've setup blog.mydomain.com to resolve to mydomain.com in DNS
but the problem is no matter how I try to write the config file, things went wrong

```
<VirtualHost sub.mydomain.com:80>
        ServerName blog.gespiton.cn
        ProxyRequests On
        <Location />
                ProxyPreserveHost On
                ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

when I write **sub.mydomain.com** as virturalhost, it has none effect. but if I change it to ***:80**, all the urls are routed to mydomain.com:8000
how can I only route sub.mydomain.com to 8000 port and mydomain.com in port 80

Comment: You want `ServerName sub.mydomain.com`... That one is relevant for the http server to decide which virtual server to use for an incoming request. And you probably want `*:80` for _all_ your virtual hosts.

Comment: Never use names in Virtualhost directive, use *:80 or ip:80 and then define the appropiate ServerName in each virtualhost like arkascha suggests. Also tell if this is 2.2 or 2.4. About reverse proxying from one virtualhost to another, why not just have ServerAlias and make all requests land in the same virtualhost? Specially since you proxy all "/"